# Do we have to include seasonal dummy variables to SARIMA model?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, arima

If we want to include a seasonal component in ARIMA model we have to include dummy variables. Another way to deal with seasonality in time series data is to consider SARIMA model, but could you please tell me, whether we need to include dummy variables also in SARIMA model or we don't need to?